# Qual é utilidade da pseudo classe :root?

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou aprendendo sobre pseudo classes estruturais, mas ainda não encontrei um artigo sobre essa pseudo classe, e tbm só encontro em inglês.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O `:root` em documentos html sempre vai se referir ao elemento `<html>`, pois mesmo que você crie um elemento "customizado" no lugar de `<html>` o motor do browser sempre vai gerar o HTML novamente.

Ele pode ser usado quando você vai compartilhar um CSS em mais de um tipo de documento, como um HTML e um XML que pode ser customizado, um exemplo é o SVG:

- global.css

  ```
  :root {
    /*estilo que vai servir para vários documentos*/
  }
  ```
- SVG:

  ```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <link href="global.css" type="text/css" />

    <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100"
        style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/>
  </svg>
  ```
- html:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title></title>
      <link href="global.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Outro local que o `:root` pode ser interessante pra estruturas XML quando vai se aplicar [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/standards/xml/transformation), os XSLT são arquivos de estilo e estrutura para XSL (não confundir com XLS que é um formato de documento do office) que este por sua vez é uma estrutura HTML embutida em um XML, basicamente os XSLs são XMLs que conseguem transformar o seu XML em algo visual equivalente ao HTML, tendo condições como IF e FOR.

Como um desenvolvedor XML pode ter diferentes documentos com diferentes elementos superiores e ainda sim usarem um mesmo CSS o `:root` pode ajudar a englobar todos (se bem que tenho quase certeza que todos XSL é convertido para HTML pelo motor do navegador)

Answer (score 8):

O CSS não precisa ser aplicado necessariamente ao HTML, certo? Ele é uma forma de estilizar documentos. Como se referencia ao elemento que dá origem a todos os outros? Ou seja, o que é em termo genéricos o elemento que contém todos ou outros? Esse é elemento é conhecido como `:root`.

Se estiver usando uma página HTML é é o equivalente ao `<HTML>`.

Se for um SVG, então ele é o `<SVG>`.

Embora possa ser usado em vários tipos de documentos, só faz sentido naqueles que cabem estilização.

[Documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#root-pseudo).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).