# O que significa o "--" especificado no :root do CSS do Bootstrap?

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap

É só uma dúvida que surgiu quando bisbilhotava o CSS do Bootstrap, isso é algo que desconheço e não achei resposta no google sobre isso...

Vai um trecho do código:

```
    :root {
      --blue: #007bff;
      --indigo: #6610f2;
      --purple: #6f42c1;
      --pink: #e83e8c;
      ...
```

O que o `--` antes de `blue` e dos outros significa exatamente?

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Qual é utilidade da pseudo classe :root?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171132/3635)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> O `:root` CSS pseudo-class representa o elemento root da arvore do
>   documento. Aplicado ao HTML, :root representa o elemento `<html>`  e é
>   idêntico ao seletor html, exceto que sua especificidade é mais alta.

No caso do Bootstrap no `:root` eles declaram algumas variáveis globais para o documento, como a Tipografia a paleta de cores e os *breakpoint*

**Sobre os "--" veja o que diz a documentação oficial W3C:**

> A custom property is any property whose name starts with two dashes
>   (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS), like --foo.

***Ou seja é a propriedade que começa com dois traços*** <kbd>--</kbd>

Link da documentação W3C sobre **custom property** https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#defining-variables

Essas cores como `--blue:#007bff;` são na verdade CSS-Variables, então como ele declara no :root que a cor `--blue` tem como valor `#007bff`, depois ele pode colocar em um texto  `color:var(--blue)` e ele na verdade vai pegar o valor `#007bff`

O legal das variáveis é que vc pode usa-la em qualquer elementos e depois facilmente trocar o tema do site inteiro só mudando o valor que está na variável, é tipo um CSS dentro do CSS, trocando o valor da variável global que está no `:root` vc troca o site inteiro, podendo ser uma cor, font-family, etc...

Veja o exemplo abaixo para ver como funciona. Nele eu declarei que `--azul` é `blue`, mas se eu trocar `blue` por `red` todos os elementos com a variável `--azul` ficam `red`.

**OBS:** no exemplo abaixo o valor `#0f0` é um *fallback* caso o browser não de suporte a variável `--azul`, assim ele vai usar a cor que vem após a vírgula (verde).

Repare que eu usei a variável `var(--azul)` tanto para determinar o `color` da font assim como a cor do `background-color`.

```css
:root {
  --azul: blue;
}
p {
  color: var(--azul);
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: var(--azul, #0f0);
}
/* repare que a variável --azullll não existe e o fallback é #0f0 então ela fica verde*/
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: var(--azullll, #0f0);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

---

**DICA:**

Outra opção de uso. Agora em vez de declarar o valor da propriedade de forma variável eu vou declarar a propriedade como um variável, e quando eu usa-la no estilo do elemento eu apenas mudo com o valor que eu quero.

Primeiro setei um variável no seletor universal `* {}` e depois chamei o valor `--mb: Npx` dela direto no elemento. Dessa forma em qualquer elemento que vc colocar `--mb + valor` vc vai estar dando um `margin-bottom` do tamanho do valor

```css
* {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb, initial);
}
.item1 {
    --mb: 20px;
    background: red;
}
.item2, .item3 {
   --mb: 40px;
   background: blue;
}
.item3 {
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="item1">item1</div>
<div class="item2">item2</div>
<div class="item3">item3</div>
<div class="">item4</div>
```

**OBS:** O `initial` nesse caso é o *fallback* , então caso vc não sete a variável em algum elemento o valor `initial` fica valendo evitando efeitos colaterais indesejados.

Vc pode ler mais na documentação oficial da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/var

Consulte aqui o suporte dos browsers a `css-variables`, vejam que é amplamente aceite, e para o IE que não aceita fica valendo o  *fallback* valor após a virgula https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

---

Tudo que vc colocar de estilo no `:root` fica valendo para o documento todo, mas em alguns casos vc pode usar outras *seletores* como por exemplo o seletor universal `*` . Se vc colocar ali `font-size:20px` por exemplo, esse valor será o default para todo o texto que vc escrever no documento.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:root

**Root completo do Bootstrap 4**

```
:root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
  ...
  --breakpoint-xs: 0;
  --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
  --breakpoint-md: 768px;
  --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
  --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
  --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

Veja que além das cores eles tb declaram a Tipografia etc. Se vc quiser usar o **Google Fonte** basta trocar a `--font-family` ali e pronto, seu site todo terá uma nova font global.

Comment: achava que não era possível criar variáveis no css, somente no less, sass, etc... obrigado pela aula...

Comment: @SamuelMota Sim as variáveis são um recurso poderoso e muito bem aceito pelos browsers modernos, menos o IE, mas para ele fica valendo o fallback, que [e o valor apos a virgula como expliquei acima. Veja o suporte dos browsers a propriedade https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables