# Há como acessar um valor por CSS?

Tags: css

Estou tentando ajustar uma imagem no css no meu site, e quero extender a imagem na tela toda, só que para isso tenho que atribuir à minha imagem: `margin-left`, para corrigir a posicionamento da tela.

Só que o valor que irei atribuir nesse campo é o soma dos sequintes valores, que são as margens dos containers.

```
$('.row').css('margin-left');
"0px"
$('.article-body').css('margin-left');
"103.875px"
$('.article-body').css('padding-left');
"18.75px"
```

O que quero saber é se no css, consigo pegar esses valores para fazer algo do tipo, considerando é claro que esses valores irão mudar com o redimensionamento da tela.

```
element-style{
  margin-left: '.article-body'.marginleft + '.article...
}
```

Comment: Não consegue. Mas se a imagem se estenderá pela tela inteira, por que não utilizar *width* 100%?

Comment: Fiz isso, mas o pai é limitado por essas margens, eu setei o `width: 100vw;
    max-width: initial;` para colocar a imagem no tamanho que quero , só que a margen ainda joga ele para a direita.

Comment: O detalhe é que se eu colocar 100% o tamanho da imagem fica limitado pela row.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, se é que entendi, o seu problema não é com as margens... isso que vc está tentando fazer é provavelmente uma gambiarra para corrigir outro problema que vc ainda não identificou e que deveria ser corrigido...

Comment: Sim, é um problema que estou tentando consertar, mas pensei nessa solução e como sou iniciante em css, queria saber se é possível fazer essa esse tipo coisa.

Comment: Talvez se você colocar todo o código do menu e do css, fique mais claro para nós!

Comment: A minha duvida mesmo era essa, eu até pensei em colocar o codigo do problema em si, mas é muito codigo e eu teria que simplificar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tecnicamente não. Mas existe uma função chamada `calc()`, que calcula os valores (0px, 0%, 0cm, ..), por exemplo:

```
.teste{
   margin-left: calc(1px + 3px + 4px, ..)
}
```

Uma opção são as variaveis:

```
:root{
   --nome-variavel: valor;
}
```

Este trecho acima é uma declaração da variavel no css. E para utilizar a variavel é só utilizar o metodo `var()`.

Ela foi declarada no `:root` (html) para que nós conseguimos acessar ela a qualquer momento. No seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
:root{
     --row-margin-left: 0px;
     --article-body-margin-left: 103.875px;
     --article-body-padding-left: 18.75px;
}

.elemento{
     margin-left: calc(var(--row-margin-left) + var(--article-body-margin-left) + var(--article-body-padding-left))
}
```

Isso se equivale a colocar os valores diretamente:

```
.elemento{
     margin-left: calc(0px + 103.875px + 18.75);
}
```

Comment: Bem bacana, acho que tivemos a mesma ideia! Só faltou um "px" ai nos "18.75"

Comment: Vdd, não consigo pensar em algo mais dinâmico que isso. Valeu por achar o erro!

Answer (score 3):

sim é possível, mas vc vai precisar usar `calc()` e *custom variables* `--var` para fazer isso.

Vou fazer um exemplo básico apenas para vc entender como pode somar valores de diferentes variáveis e colocar em outro elemento. No seu caso seria fazer uma variável para cada margem e soma-las na margem de outro elemento.

Veja o exemplo, coloquei um `margin-bottom` para a primeira `div`, depois outro `margin-bottom` para a segunda `div` e na terceira `div` eu faço a soma dos dois valores do `margin-bottom` da primeira e segunda `div`s. *OBS:* Esse é apenas um exemplo didático para vc entender o conceito.

```css
:root {
  --d1m: 20px; /* valor do margin para a primeira div */
  --d2m: 40px; /* valor do margin para a segunda div */
  --dh: 20px; /* altura das div */
}
.d1, .d2, .d3, .d4 {
  height: var(--dh); /* height de 20px */
}
.d1 {
  background-color: #f00;
  margin-bottom: var(--d1m);
}
.d2 {
  background-color: #ff0;
  margin-bottom: var(--d2m);
}
.d3 {
  background-color: #0f0;
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--d1m) + var(--d2m));  /* valor somado da primeira e segunda div */
}
.d4 {
  background-color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
  <div class="d1"></div>
  <div class="d2"></div>
  <div class="d3"></div>
  <div class="d4"></div>
```

Sobre o `calc()` vc pode ler mais nessa documentação da Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

E sobre as *custom variables* vc pode ler na documentação oficial W3C https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#defining-variables ou nessa resposta [O que significa o -- especificado no :root do css do bootstrap?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298995/o-que-significa-o-especificado-no-root-do-css-do-bootstrap)