# Como herdar um valor de um determinado atributo em CSS?

Tags: html, css, atributos, height

Olá, pessoal.

Como eu faço para herdar um valor de um determinado atributo em CSS?

Exemplo:

```html
<div class="flex" id="1" style="line-height: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">1</div>
<div class="flex" id="1" style="line-height: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;">2</div>
<div class="flex" id="3" style="line-height: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green;">3</div>
```

Nesse caso, eu queria que o documento apenas se igualasse cada *line-heigh* com o *height*. Como faço isso?

Comment: Se for igualar o line-height com o height do próprio elemento, pode(deve) fazer com javascript/jQuery. Até onde sei, com CSS puro não dá pra fazer.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo seu comentário, @LipESprY porém eu tenho um preferêcia por uma solução em CSS ou HTML.

Comment: @LipESprY com CSS é possível chegar em algo bem próximo, pois vc declara um valor só que vai ser usado tanto no height quanto no line-height então vc declara apenas 1 valor, mas que fica valendo para os 2 atributos. Veja na resposta.

Comment: @higocls Sua ideia, por mais que seja interessante, continua não sendo tão dinâmico quanto o *victor sousa* pretende. Imagino que utilizar uma classe base e uma classe definidora como respondido pelo *lazyFox* é uma solução até bem próxima a sua. O trabalho do programador será o mesmo: definir o height e definir uma classe/variável para setar o line-height. Com jQuery por exemplo, basta varrer todos elementos com a classe *flex* e setar o line-height conforme o height do próprio elemento... Ficaria BEEEEM mais dinâmico...

Comment: @LipESprY pode ser mais dinâmico, mas não "MUITO" mais, até pq de qualquer forma ele sempre vai ter que declarar uma altura correto? Então sempre que ele declarar a altura o valor da variável ser igual para os dois, altura e line-height. Resumindo ele só precisa declarar 1 valor... Pelo que entendi com jQuery vc vai ter que varrer o documento, pegar o valor da altura e colocar no line-height. sinceramente não vi muita vantagem, ainda mais pensando que vc vai precisar indexar o jQuery só para isso... (caso ele não exista no projeto é claro)

Comment: @hugocsl é justo! Baseando-se na pergunta, qualquer solução não vai ser lá tão dinâmica. Se for do interesse, posso formular uma solução mais dinâmica utilizando outros métodos (CSS/HTML puro). Pelo que percebi, o objetivo é centralizar verticalmente o conteúdo da div definindo só a altura e cor de fundo. Eu faria com flexbox, mas tem como fazer com display: table|table-cell.

Comment: @LipESprY pois é, se for apenas para centralizar verticalmente eu na verdade marcaria como duplicada, pois aqui tem uma pergunta sobre isso com 23 respostas rss! Mas herdar valor de outro atributo é bem diferente de alinhar verticalmente... por isso não votei para fechar como duplicada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma opção usando CSS *variables*.

A ideia aqui parte de um valor base setado na variável `--altura`, depois vamos fazer o *overhide* (sobrescrever) o valor dessa variável onde quisermos. Repare que vc só precisa trocar o valor da variável e será substituído tanto o `height` quanto o `line-height` do elemento. Resumindo vc declara apenas 1 valor de variável que substitui o valor dos 2 atributos que vc quer mudar deixei comentado no código para facilitar

```css
:root {
  --altura: 100px; /* valor "base" */
}
.altura, .altura2, .altura3 {
    height: var(--altura); /* valor "da variável" */
    line-height: var(--altura); /* valor "da variável" */
}
.altura2 {
    --altura: 200px; /* overhide do valor da variável */
}
.altura3 {
    --altura: 300px; /* overhide do valor da variável */
}
```

```html
<div class="altura" id="1" style="background-color: red;">1</div>
<div class="altura2" id="1" style="background-color: blue;">2</div>
<div class="altura3" id="3" style="background-color: green;">3</div>
```

Consulte o suporte dos browser, repare que apenas não funciona no IE https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: Muito interessante, desconhecia estas `CSS variables`.  As variáveis estão acessiveis a todos os atributos do `CSS`? Ou existe alguma limitação?

Comment: @lazyFox da uma olhada nessa resposta que tem uma explicação mais detalhada das variáveis. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298995/o-que-significa-o-especificado-no-root-do-css-do-bootstrap/298998#298998 Mas vc também já encontra bastante material sobre isso na internet, a maioria em inglês infelizmente...

Comment: Acho que sue resposta é o mais simples que se pode alcançar apenas com o CSS. Obrigado pela reposta e obrigado a todos os outros que contribuíram.