# Mudar corpo de uma pagina com js

Tags: javascript, html, body

O que eu quero é o seguinte, eu tenho um corpo normal da minha pagina em html e quero que ao clicar em um botao com um certo ID o corpo inteiro mude para outro corpo utilizando javascript ou jquery!

(Sei muito pouco sobre js/jquery, estou aprendendo pouco a pouco)

♢ØBŘĮĞÅĐŐ♢

Comment: O corpo inteiro? Isso é muita coisa, é possível fazer mas não seria uma coisa muito "elegante". Sugiro que você continue estudando Js e quando você tiver uma boa base comece a estudar os Framework JavaScript, como o Angular por exemplo.

Comment: Mas quer mudar os estilos ou o html em si ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vai depender um pouco de como vc montou seu CSS como um todo, mas vc pode adicionar uma classe no `body` com uma nova `font-family`, e com isso tudo que estiver dentro vai herdar esse novo `font-family` da classe adicionada no `body`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse exemplo é com jQuery, e quando vc clica na no `BTN` ele adiciona a classe `.fonte` no `body` com o `font-family` novo.

```js
$( "#btn" ).click(function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("fonte");
  $(this).toggleClass("ativo");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
body.fonte {
  font-family: arial;
}
#btn.ativo {
  background-color: green;
}
#btn {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="btn">btn</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Recusandae quibusdam nostrum, eveniet ullam voluptas blanditiis quos unde pariatur maiores quasi laudantium modi dolorem officia, corporis distinctio doloribus molestias ipsa autem.</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado, graças a ti Hugocsl tive uma ideia plena!

Comment: @LuckyBlack sem problemas jovem. Se vc quiser algo mais avançado construa seu CSS usando CSS Variables, e com o JS vc muda o valor da variável, aqui vc pode ler mais sobre isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298995/o-que-significa-o-especificado-no-root-do-css-do-bootstrap/298998#298998 veja aqui tb  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002850/8953758